# What are the key differences between Tantalum and Tantalum Polymer capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, components, tantalum

I've noticed that most component retailers split these types, and am wondering what comparative differences there are between them. I know that "regular" tantalum caps usually use MnO<sub>2</sub> as an electrolyte, whereas polymer ones use (generally unspecified) polymers instead.

What are the main performance differences between them? Is there a key factor that should decide which type is used in a specific design scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Conventional MnO2 tantalum capacitors** are the ideal choice for applications with requirements for high temperatures (currently up to
> 175C), high voltage (up to 50V) and established reliability. The
> technology offers highest CV in a small package. It’s possible to use
> them up to 80% of rated voltage, but in low impedance circuits further
> derating needs to be applied - see 7].
>
> **Tantalum Polymer Capacitors** are
> the best choice for consumer applications with low ESR requirements
> such as DC/DC converters in notebooks, PDA, telecom and other
> applications. The parts can be used up to 80% of rated voltage.
> Manufacturer’s specifications of lead-free reflow process capability,
> temperature range ratings, leakage current and appropriate
> storage/handling in accordance to the MSL level should be verified for
> specific application needs.
>
> **NbO OxiCapTM Capacitors** offer the safest,
> available alternative among the various capacitor technologies with
> good cost-versus-performance value. The parts can be used up to 80% of
> rated voltage and are compatible with lead-free reflow requirements.
> The excellent steady state reliability makes these parts a favorite
> choice not only for consumer applications but also for high end,
> automotive, computer and professional designs. Appropriate temperature
> derating needs to be applied for temperatures over 85°C.

http://www.avx.com/docs/techinfo/New_Tantalum_Technologies.pdf

Comment: Interesting info. Do the realities stack up to AVX's marketing?

Comment: Unsure, I am stuck in the 90+ ambient so I can't go near these at the moment